# Upgraded to Rails 3 from 2.3.8 and I get a passenger error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache

I recently upgraded from Rails 2.3.8 to Rails 3, and I am now getting this passenger error:

Welcome to the Phusion Passenger Apache 2 module installer, v3.0.13.

This installer will guide you through the entire installation process. It
shouldn't take more than 3 minutes in total.

Here's what you can expect from the installation process:

1. The Apache 2 module will be installed for you.
2. You'll learn how to configure Apache.
3. You'll learn how to deploy a Ruby on Rails application.

Don't worry if anything goes wrong. This installer will advise you on how to
solve any problems.

Press Enter to continue, or Ctrl-C to abort.

---

Checking for required software...

- GNU C++ compiler... found at /usr/bin/g++
- Curl development headers with SSL support... found
- OpenSSL development headers... found
- Zlib development headers... found
- Ruby development headers... found
- OpenSSL support for Ruby... found
- RubyGems... found
  Unable to autodetect the currently active RVM gem set name. Please contact this program's author for support.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using RVM to manage which ruby version is installed? Maybe try using the default system ruby `rvm use system`. I personally use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/) to manage ruby versions.

Comment: Installed the passenger gen and then passenger-install-apache2-module

We also have rvm installed